# How can I get a voluntary text fragment within start and end index

Tags: fabricjs

I need to get text within start and end index.

For example for a text like
"*Fabric.js is a powerful and simple Javascript HTML5 canvas library*"
for start index "0" and end index "8" it must show the result "*Fabric.js*".

Is there a method similar to getSelectedText(start, end)?
With the difference that I need to get a voluntary text fragment, not the selected one

Comment: is this what you were looking for, or was it something else? Could you mark the answer as accepted if that was it? TY!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda vague. I am not sure I understand what you mean by 'voluntary text fragment'.

However, if you are using a `fabric.IText` instance, you can use the following attributes to get/set the start & end of the text selection :

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('Canvas');

var myText = new fabric.IText('Fabric.js is a powerful and simple Javascript HTML5 canvas library',{
top: 50,
left: 50,
fontSize: 20
});

canvas.add(myText);
canvas.renderAll();

myText.enterEditing(); // Enter text editing mode
myText.selectionStart = 0;
myText.selectionEnd = 9;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.js"
    integrity="sha512-CzyxOXSECwo2nGJQZ2P8fdDxWVMVzn0jNdT2lYJ3afbqDJbaQ4qxgv9sLc85f6KP8HO2y929Bu+lnPKGC3ofSg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <canvas id="Canvas" width="700" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, it's not the point. I'm searching for a method which returns the text. Like getSelectedText()

Comment: @AntonAntonoff You really need to be + specific. By adding `myText.getSelectedText()` at the end of my code example, you can recover the text that was selected. So what is it exactly that you want?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask